# c# gRPC one class/service that implements multiple protos - 1 for public methods and 1 for private

Tags: c#, grpc

I have server architecture that I am wanting to replatform from WCF to gRPC but am stuck.  The main service provides a wealth of functionality including dynamically binding to subservers, and so a number of methods are very private, and there are of course a dozen or so public methods.  I have developed the protos but have no idea how to implement 2 protos in 1 c# class?

We clearly dont have MI; is there a way of generating interfaces rather than abstract classes?

Here is our topology - all services on left are public and those on right private - the Site Manager supports both

[image: Toplogy]

Comment: What problem would be solved when you have 1 instead of 2 classes?

Comment: The private services would be on a different port, unreachable from client.

Comment: Regarding your question *"Is there a way of generating interfaces rather than abstract services?"* -> Yes, if both the client and server is written in C#, you can use [protobuf-net](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net)

Comment: Thanks @dan-kli I will look at that today.  I have made a small demo app to demonstrate the issue - basically no multiple inheritance and code generation builds abstract classes rather than interfaces.

Comment: Yes, the default way with the protobuf compiler protoc generates abstract C# classes from the proto files (for the service). If you use protobuf-net, you can define interfaces instead.